# Project screen point onto 3D ground plane

Tags: 3d, linear-algebra, perspectivecamera

I need to project points on the screen onto the ground plane of a 3D scene rendered by a perspective camera. Givens:

- The coordinate system happens to be left-handed, Y-up.
- I know the total vertical and horizontal FoV of my camera (let's call them `F` and `G`, respectively; half of each is `f` and `g`).
- The camera is a point `E` looking at the origin `O`. (Alternatively, it is specified in spherical coordinates as a distance `d` away from the original, an angle `r` rotated up from the ground plane, and an angle `t` rotated around the vertical +y axis.)
- For simplicity, let's say that the screen points are specified as percentages away from the middle towards the edge. (In other words, a point on the center of the screen is `0,0`, a point at the bottom middle is `0,-1`, top right corner is `1,1`, etc.)
- It is a given that the ground plane is always within view of the camera (the camera is not allowed to tilt down so low that any points above the horizon are on screen).

Working from 2D I have a solution that works if the screen points are only in the centerline of the screen (x=0). However, I can't figure out how to take X offsets into account.

---

Here's what I have so far. We ignore the `t` rotation around the vertical and work in 2D.

[image: complex 2D diagram exhibiting the problem]

- `O` is the origin of the camera (the 'look at target' of the camera)
- `E` is the eye point of the camera
- `P` is the point we are trying to find (or really the distance `n`)
- `r` is the tilt angle of the camera (known)
- `d` is the distance between `E` and `O` (known)
- `f` is half the total vertical FoV of the camera
- We know that the y value of the screen point `screenYPct` is the same as the ratio `a/(a+b)`

We find the angle `g` in terms of `screenYPct` and `f` as:

```
tan(g) = a/(bottom of upper triangle)
tan(f) = (a+b)/(bottom of upper triangle)
a/(a+b) = tan(g)/tan(f)
g = atan( screenYPct * tan(f) )
```

The height `y` of the eye point is: `d * sin(r)`
The ground distance `m` between the eye point and the camera origin is: `d * cos(r)`
The angle `s` (in degrees) is just: `90-r`
The distance `n` (between `P` and the origin `O`) is thus found by:

```
tan(g+s) = (m+n)/y
n = y * tan(g+s) - m
n = d * ( sin(r) * tan(atan( screenYPct * tan(f) ) + 90 - r) - cos(r) )
```

Given `n`, I can then rotate `P` around the origin on the ground plane by the angle `t` to find the ground `(x,z)` point of `P`.

But…again, that's all assuming that the original screen point is in the horizontal middle of the screen. How can I find the point on the ground when the screen point deviates from the midline?

Comment: For the curious, the motivation for this is to track multi-touch points in a custom 3D engine to ensure that pinch/zoom/rotate/pan gestures keep points of the geometry always under the fingers.

Comment: I believe I've got it; need to code it up to test before I write an answer, but the key is to find the horizontal angle deviation similar to `g`, and then use the distance from `E` to `P` to find how far to move orthogonally before rotating around `t`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to simply cast a ray in world coordinates from the given screen coordinates and intersect this ray with the ground plane?

Comment: @user3146587 If I had the matrix of the camera, then yes, the code would be easier for me (though end up using slightly more unnecessary math). However, I don't have the current camera transform matrix available.

Comment: How can one expect recovering an accurate intersection with the ground plane without having the actual transform/projection to map from world to screen coordinates. You should at least have all the parameters necessary to compute the transform/projection matrix, right?

Comment: @user3146587 Yes, I have the information necessary to construct a full matrix. Computing the full matrix, then using that to project a screen point out in order to create a ray, and then performing the arbitrary ray-plane intersection, however, is both far more code and far more computation time than is necessary.

Comment: @Phrogz I'm have a related problem, except I'm working with an isometric viewing system and I'm using quaternions to represent the plane in the scene and the viewing plane.  Essentially the viewing plane has zero rotation. The plane in the scene has an origin and an orientation relative to the viewing plane.  I have the orthogonal matrices for both planes.  Any guess on how this might be done?  I can ask a new question if that would help.